# how to run 32 bit jar on 64 bit jvm

Tags: java, jar, jvm

I downloaded a java app (a desktop LogCat viewer from android logs) and am trying to run it.  My problem is that I amm getting an error that seems to imply I cannot run a 32 bit java app on a 64 bit jvm.  The stack trace is below.

I need to point out that I cannot change the source.  I don't have access to it.  I need to know how I can configure my jvm to run the jar.  I'm running in Windows 7.

```
> java -jar LogcatOfflineViewer_20120505.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.logcat.offline.UIThread.runUI(UIThread.java:112)
        at com.logcat.offline.Main.main(Main.java:6)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: You either need a 32 bit jvm or a 64 bit export of that SWT application.

Comment: you might wana try installing 32 bit jre

Comment: @RobinChander Is there no way to run the 64 bit jvm in some sort of compatibility mode?  That seems like a pretty major oversight by Oracle

Comment: @ewok its go nothing to do with Java, Oracle or JVMs. Its how applications run on just about every OS.

Comment: @ewok how u overcome with this prob?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A JAR is not 32-bit or 64-bit, it can run on either JVM.

However, a native shared library is either 32-bit or 64-bit and it can run only with a JVM with that bitness.  This is a limitation of the way application run on Windows and Linux (and every other OS AFAIK) There is no way to load a 64-bit library on a 32-bit JVm or visa-versa.  You need to match your sahred libraries versions with your JVM.

Comment: @Krishna  This is a limitation imposed by the OS and to some degree is fundamental to the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit applications.

Comment: so there is no way of executing any 32 bit application on 64 bit mac os is it? because i need to execute that application on 64 bit mac i mean that swt application. can u give me some idea

Comment: @Krishna You can't run a 32-bit application with 64-bit libraries.  Most 64-bit OSes have 32-bit emulators and 32-bit libraries as well.

Comment: they is there any indirect way to do this?

Comment: @Krishna Yes, you can have a 64-bit JVM talk to a 32-bit JVM running a 32-bit DLL/shared library.  You can also have a 32-bit JVM talking to a 64-bit JVM running a 64-bit DLL/shared library.  i.e. use RMI or RPC/JMS.

Comment: Please can u explain how to do that? and where i can find this DLL/shared Library. ?

Comment: @Krishna I am assuming you have a DLL/Shared library already as this is the point of the question.  If you don't know where to find it, you don't have a problem. ;)

Comment: so is there any changes that i have to make for that? and tell me na how to do it?

Comment: @Krishna I don't understand what your specific problem is, so I don't know what you need to change.  I suggest you write a new question, describing what you are doing, what the problem is, including any code and errors, and what you have tried.

Comment: Well i need to Run Dj native swing application in mac. but thing is that its giving error of cant load 32 Jvm Libraries into the 64bit jvm i solved that prob with windows but still not solved for Mac.

Comment: You need to obtain the 64-bit library to run in a 64-bit JVM.  Or you need to learn how to use RMI between two processes.

Comment: Can u give me link for swt 64 bit library for mac. ? and ya or please give me link for RMI

Comment: @Krishna Are you using Swing or SWT because you shouldn't be using both AFAIK.  I suggest you use google to find these.

Comment: i have google a lot for this. yes i am using swt libraries. i solved everything just remaining for mac only. but m not able to find that :(

Comment: still have not find anything that help me with mac os all time when i run that its giving error that swt version 4.3 or later require or sometime its giving that 32 bit libraries cant be load in 64bit jvm and all

Comment: Here the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707562/dj-native-swing-browser-in-java-swing-for-mac

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which I solved ensuring to run my jar on the correct jvm by giving the full path in the command prompt (I had already 2 versions of java in my system)

It seems that you can also  use the -d32 or -d64 switch, even if in my system that didn't work (see this and other alternatives is [How to run 32-bit Java on Mac OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942063/how-to-run-32-bit-java-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion) )