# Mac OS X - 32bit Java VM?

Tags: java, jvm, 32-bit

I'm using libraries within my project only supported in 32bit VM - I'm using Mac OS X Maverick. There does not seem to be a 32-Bit Java Version for Mac. How can I run my application in 32bit Modus from eclipse?

Comment: Download eclipse with the java integrated.

Comment: You might try installing [*Java for OS X 2013-005*](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942063/how-to-run-32-bit-java-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion for the same question on Lion. Perhaps you can pass the same parameter?