# How to get Java 32bit in Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: java, xmpp, osx-mavericks, openfire

I'm trying to set up an Openfire XMPP server on my MAC, however the problem is that I needed to upgrade to Maverick for Titanium and once you upgrade to Maverick Java updates to a 64bit rather than the 32bit that is needed for Openfire.

How can I get the Java 32bit again?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942063/how-to-run-32-bit-java-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion) Should help you on understanding how to run a 32-Bit java environment with the -d32 switch. However, the most recent version of Openfire should be 64bit compatible, found [here](https://igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp).